# Stripe Dynamic Amount with charge.php on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I need to implement a payment with Stripe to charge a racing fee. The problem is the fees are calculate on the size of the boat.

Example : 
20-29 feet > Price of the foot : 12 $ 
30-39 feet > Price of the foot : 16 $

Stripe Plugin for wordpress don't allow you to achieve this. So i need to use charge.php

For the moment, i have my charge.php like this :

```
<?php // Get boat value. Apply some simple security here (apply further if 
putting in DB later)
isset ($_POST['boat_value']) ? $boat_value = $_POST['boat_value'] : '';

// Charge the user's card with variable amount:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => $boat_value,
"currency" => "eur",
"description" => "Example charge",
"source" => $token,
));
```

and my index.php like this

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
<select name="boat_value" id="boat_value" required>
<option selected="selected" disabled>Choose boat size</option>
<option value="1200">20 - 29 ft</option>
<option value="1600">30 - 39 ft</option>
</select>
</form>
```

That doesn't work ! What is missing ?

Thanks !

Comment: you get your post data in chrage .php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using WP Simple Pay Pro and/or Gravity Forms with their Stripe integration. Both plugins support variable amounts with a custom form.

Comment: I already use this plugin but, to my knowledge,  there is no way to calculate the amount according to the number of foot of the boat.

Comment: I find out with the new version of WP Simple Pay Pro (3.1). Thank you for the advice ! Problem solve !

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally figured this out for myself tonight.

Directory structure should look like:

`--theme-root
--js
----stripe.js
--Stripe
----init.php
--charge.php
--tpl_demo.php`

First you will need to download the latest stripe php library and include it in the root of your theme. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases. I unzipped it and renamed the folder to Stripe, just to make sure 'Stripe/init.php' is available.

Then in functions.php add 
    `wp_enqueue_script( 'qbtv_stripe_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/stripe.js', array(), '', true );`
    `wp_enqueue_script( 'stripe_js', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3', array(), '', false );`

Here is a gist on github with the three files you will need:
https://gist.github.com/jimboobrien/307cdd715178a5967531343922072c29

**form.php** - the html/php you should put in a template file in the theme
**charge.php** - the file you should include in the root of your theme or child theme along with the Stripe folder
**stripe.js** - the js file you sould include in your js folder in your theme

Message me if you have any problems I can help. Let's get this working on Stripe's v3 php elements API!

- Jim

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. I figure out with Simple Pay Pro v3 plugin. But when i would have a little time, i'll try your solution on a dev website. ;)

Comment: No problem, try out the gist and everything should be good. I changed it to send an email now as well. Let me know if you need assistance.

Comment: Thank you @jimboobrien It works perfectly. I finally found the time to test your solution. ^^ 
 Do you know if i can use a custom payment + a one time payment on the same charge.php. 
Means that the customer can pay his registration and add to that payment a custom donation. Do you think it's possible ?

Comment: Of course! I responded here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286398/stripe-custom-checkout-with-dynamically-amount/47289357#47289357

Answer (score 0):

Please check console.log first if there is error related to a JS.

Check posted data are available in charge.php file.

Please verify that you have included following in top of file.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I understand more my error. I think I need to implement the stripe library first on wordpress. Do you know how to do that properly ?